# PHP sequence of executed queries in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

If I have a bunch of queries in PHP, assuming that i'm using PDO, these queries will be executed in sequence, but PHP or MySQL will wait one query to finish before start a new one?

```
$sql1 = $con->prepare("some query");
$sql2 = $con->prepare("some query");   
$sql3 = $con->prepare("some query");

$sql1->execute();
$sql2->execute();
$sql3->execute();
```

And if I use a transactional block in PDO with the same queries:

```
$con->beginTransaction();
```

Will the execution be the same?

Comment: Is execution is different ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A query is a single SQL statement that does Select, Update, Insert or Delete of rows.

A transaction is a consecutive sequence of SQL statements (from the application viewpoint) that have the "ACID" properties:

- Atomicity: All statements or none are executed.
- Consistency: Data integrity is always maintained.
- Isolation: Transaction A can never affect Transaction B.
- Durability: Changes that are committed by a transaction persist, even in event of system failure.

Comment: so if I don't use the transaction, I can take risks that the third query could be finished before the second one.

Comment: No, in your example `$sql3` will **always** start after `$sql2` is finished.

Comment: php is in order processed it can never execute line 2 until after line 1 is processed.